# Which crime is done or law violated when a person pushes other to commit suicide?

Tags: united-states

In Argentina there is a crime that's called "suicidio inducido" (induced suicide)  that's when a person physically or psychologically pushes another to commit suicide. I looked for a crime like this (induced suicide) in English but I couldnt find a reference. Is there such crime or which charge would be applied to a person doing such thing in United States?

Comment: It is  involuntary manslaughter,  not murder, according to the case here: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/21859/2804

Answer (score 1):

The crime exists in Australia - it’s called murder.

Comment: It is  involuntary manslaughter,  not murder, according to the case here: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/21859/2804